# Drop multiple database in PostgreSQL using a wildcard

Tags: postgresql

Often while adding a feature to an existing project i have something like ( result of listing the databases )

```
project_x_001, ..., project_x_00n
```

I need to clean the database at the end, by dropping all the database that start with a certain pattern, in this case project_x_*

is there any elegant ( cleaner ) to do this in PostgreSQL, beside:

```
drop database project_x_001, ..., project_x_00n;
```

the list sometimes is too long, and you would need at each time list the databases and delete a chunk of them

Answer (score 14):

the following solution applies to Ubuntu

```
for db in `psql -c '\l' | grep project_x_* | cut -d '|' -f 1`; do psql -c "drop database $db"; done
```

basically the above command loops over the selected databases using grep; please see the result of that selection before dropping anything from the database.

Comment: Change this to use `psql -X` to make sure it ignores your `.psqlrc` custom format  - it can mess the grep

Answer (score 2):

I needed a slight modification on @rachid's answer because my DB names resulted in an invalid syntax from character: "-"

My DB names where named horribly like `testrun-ppsubscriptions-1597745672749-276`

So needed to modify it as:

```
for db in `psql -c '\l' | grep testrun* | cut -d '|' -f 1`; do psql -c "drop database \"$db\" "; done
```

Thanks @rachid!

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html).

Comment: I agree it is not possible using only SQL, i would love to know if there's a hacky way to do it.